# set directory in assembly

Tags: assembly, directory, dos, x86-16, qemu

I have just written a simple kernel code that set directory. the code quite simple :

```
call Set_Directory
call Processed_Exit

Write:
mov al,[si]
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
inc si
mov dl,[si]
cmp dl,0x00
jne Write
ret

Set_Directory:
xor ax,ax
mov ah,0x3b
xor dx,dx
mov dx,DirectoryY
int 0x21
cmp al,0x03
je Terminated_Exit
cmp al,0x05
je Terminated_Exit
cmp al,0x06
je Terminated_Exit
cmp al,0x10
je Terminated_Exit
ret

Processed_Exit:
mov si,Processed
call Write
int 0x19

Terminated_Exit:
mov si,Terminated
call Write
int 0x19

Processed db 'Processed',0
Terminated db 'Terminated',0
DirectoryX db 'X'
DirectoryY db 'Y'
```

I know I don't have a Y directory (I'm trying to create a directory for my own operating system)
I'm just trying to get the error correctly if I didn't have such a directory. I checked the error values in [http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah39](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html#ah39)

the return values on error are `0x03 - 0x05 - 0x06 - 0x10` as you see in my program, I wrote if the ax was equal to those values print "Terminated" but it prints "Processed" and then reboot

why I get this output?

this is the code which I used for creating a directory I don't know if it really worked or not because I can't get an error on set directory to X

```
Create_Directory:
xor ax,ax
mov ah,0x39
mov dx,Directory
int 0x21
cmp al,0x03
je Terminated_Exit
cmp al,0x05
je Terminated_Exit
ret
```

is this even a write way to create a directory or set directory :/ ?

I use NASM and the code will run on Qemu

thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, path names need to be null-terminated, so you want `DirectoryX db 'X', 0` and so forth.  Also, the correct way to check for an error return from a DOS call is to test the carry flag; only if it is set can you expect the error code in AX to be meaningful.  And note that if there is an error, the error code could be something other than one of the possibilities you explicitly test.

Comment: Are you running this under actual DOS, or under your own OS?

Comment: Under dosbox, the chdir call fails with AL=03h and prints out the Terminated message as expected.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using qemu for emulation on Linux. I'll check DOSBox too. thankyou

Comment: Yeah, but qemu only emulates the hardware.  I'm asking about the operating system you are running inside it.

Comment: Just a guess, but are you thinking that directory creation is a service provided by the BIOS, like your character output with `int 0x10`?  It's not, it's a DOS service.  If you have booted your own kernel, then DOS is not there and there are no filesystem services at all unless you write them.  This is the case for all `int 21h` services.

Comment: @NateEldredge I run my .bin file directly without any operating system. I run my .bin file directly with the command : ```qemu-system-x86_64 OS.bin``` in terminal then qemu will run it as OS. as you said I'm trying to run it in DOSBox now. I'm searching about how to convert bin to iso then run It inside DOSBOX... . I'll keep you inform if it worked.

Comment: Okay, well then you can't expect any of the `int 21h` calls to work, until you write the code for them to do something.  DOSBox is, well, DOS; you can't have your OS and also DOS both.  When I tested your file I ran it as a .com executable under DOS, since that's what I incorrectly assumed you intended.  But there's no point in you trying it now.

Comment: @NateEldredge took some time, couldn't run on DOSBox, then did it on a virtual machine. worked fine and it gave me "Process Terminated" but I used ```mov ah,0x39 & int 21h``` to create a directory with that name then set the directory to it, it still gives me "Terminated" the set function cause error no error on creating (carry flag is 0 on that).